# Update list items based on months in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collections of records in list. Now I have a data table with few records. My list sample is here:

```csh
List<TimeControlGrid> EmpList = new List<TimeControlGrid>();
EmpList = (from DataRow dr in Oracleresult.Rows
            select new TimeControlGrid()
            {
                EmpNumber = Convert.ToInt32(dr["EMPNUMBER"]),
                EmpName = dr["EMPNAME"].ToString(),
                Dept = dr["DEPT"].ToString(),
                ProjectName = dr["PROJECTNAME"].ToString(),
                ChargeDesc = dr["CHARGEDESC"].ToString(),
                ProjectCode= dr["PROJECTCODE"].ToString(),
                CostCenter= dr["COSTCENTER"].ToString(),
                Jan = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Jan"]),
                Feb = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Feb"]),
                Mar = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Mar"]),
                Apr = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Apr"]),
                May = Convert.ToInt32(dr["May"]),
                Jun = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Jun"]),
                Jul = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Jul"]),
                Aug = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Aug"]),
                Sep = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Sep"]),
                Oct = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Oct"]),
                Nov = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Nov"]),
                Dec = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Dec"]) )
            }).ToList();
```

I have a datatable with same columns but it has few value changes in months columns, so here is my requirement:

First I need to get current month. If current month is **Jan** then I need to update all months values for that record in list with data table values.

Suppose if current month value is **Dec** then I need to update only **Dec** month value in list with data table values. Below is the code sample where I need to apply my changes. In below code I am just checking with month. Current month is **Dec**. So, I just need to update **Dec** value only. Like this way suppose if current month is **Nov** then I need to update **Nov** and **Dec** values in emplist.

```csh
foreach(DataRow dr in SQLresult.Rows)
{
    var obj = EmpList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmpName == dr["EmpName"].ToString() && x.ProjectName== dr["EmpName"].ToString() && x.ChargeDesc == dr["ChargeDesc"].ToString() && x.CostCenter == dr["CostCenter"].ToString());
    if (obj != null)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() == "12")
        {
            obj.Dec = dr["Dec"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You appear to be using the `HOURS` column for all months - that doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: according to your code logic you could simply write : `HoursYTD = (Convert.ToInt32(dr["HOURS"]) * 12` am I wrong? since `dr["HOURS"]` will give you **always** the same value.

Comment: What does "if current month is jan then i need to update all months values for that record in list with data table values" mean? I just don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: for `DateTime.Now.Month.ToString()` I get "12", not "Dec". A better way is to check `DateTime.Now.Month == 12` (you probably still need `dr["Dec"]`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, then this would solve it (though it's quite ugly).

```cs
foreach (DataRow dr in SQLresult.Rows)
{
    var obj = EmpList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmpName == dr["EmpName"].ToString() && x.ProjectName == dr["EmpName"].ToString() && x.ChargeDesc == dr["ChargeDesc"].ToString() && x.CostCenter == dr["CostCenter"].ToString());
    if (obj != null)
    {
        switch (DateTime.Now.Month)
        {
            case 1:
                obj.Jan = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Jan"]);
                goto case 2;
            case 2:
                obj.Feb = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Feb"]);
                goto case 3;
            case 3:
                obj.Mar = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Mar"]);
                goto case 4;
            case 4:
                obj.Apr = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Apr"]);
                goto case 5;
            case 5:
                obj.May = Convert.ToInt32(dr["May"]);
                goto case 6;
            case 6:
                obj.Jun = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Jun"]);
                goto case 7;
            case 7:
                obj.Jul = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Jul"]);
                goto case 8;
            case 8:
                obj.Aug = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Aug"]);
                goto case 9;
            case 9:
                obj.Sep = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Sep"]);
                goto case 10;
            case 10:
                obj.Oct = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Oct"]);
                goto case 11;
            case 11:
                obj.Nov = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Nov"]);
                goto case 12;
            case 12:
                obj.Dec = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Dec"]);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

### A Possible, Cleaner Alternative

If changing the `TimeControlGrid` class is an option, I'd suggest the following:

**1. Replace all those distinct properties that represent the months with an array.**

```cs
public class TimeControlGrid
{
    public int EmpNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public string Dept { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string ChargeDesc { get; set; }
    public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
    public string CostCenter { get; set; }
    public int[] Months { get; set; }
}
```

**2. Instantiate a dictionary to use as a mapper.**

```cs
var monthMapper = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { 1, "Jan" },
    { 2, "Feb" },
    { 3, "Mar" },
    { 4, "Apr" },
    { 5, "May" },
    { 6, "Jun" },
    { 7, "Jul" },
    { 8, "Aug" },
    { 9, "Sep" },
    { 10, "Oct" },
    { 11, "Nov" },
    { 12, "Dec" }
};
```

**3. Use for loop instead of the switch.**

```cs
foreach (DataRow dr in SQLresult.Rows)
{
    var obj = EmpList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmpName == dr["EmpName"].ToString() && x.ProjectName == dr["EmpName"].ToString() && x.ChargeDesc == dr["ChargeDesc"].ToString() && x.CostCenter == dr["CostCenter"].ToString());
    if (obj != null)
        for (int i = DateTime.Now.Month; i <= 12; i++)
            obj.Months[i - 1] = Convert.ToInt32(dr[monthMapper[i]]);
}
```